# Multiple RequestMatchers for different Users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a project which needs to restrict access to certain Endpoints which cannot easily be determined via Paths (antmatchers) but need instead be determined via different aspects of the incoming request.

**For example
There are 3 Roles:**

- Admin: May use everything without restrictions
- Editor: May read anything and can Edit certain entities but cannot delete anything.
- User: May only read certain things (certain GET-Methods are allowed)
- There is also a /signin Endpoint, which is reachable for anyone (takes username/password and returns JWT)

**The Scenario:**

Repository gives the Endpoint for Entitiy A with the path : "/A". This includes GET,PUT,DELETE,POST, etc.

Then there is Repository B with path: "/B" offering the same RequestMethods.

Additionally there are two Controllers "ControllerA" and "ControllerB" with Endpoints "/EntityA/getAdditionalInformation" and "/EntityB/getAdditionalInformation" with RequestMethod GET as well as "/EntityA/editAdditionalInformation" and "/EntityB/editAdditionalInformation" with RequestMethod PATCH and finally "/EntityA/deleteAdditionalInformation" and "/EntityB/deleteAdditionalInformation" with RequestMethod DELETE.

- The Admin needs to get full access to all Endpoints.
- The Editor may read entity A and may read and update entity B and the
  corresponding information but may delete neither.
- The User may only read entity A and not the corresponding
  Information.

I tried Using RequestMatchers in the WebSecurityConfig Class like this:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(req -> (req.getRequestURI().contains("B") && !req.getRequestURI().contains("delete") && !req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.DELETE.toString())
                            || (req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.toString())
                                    && req.getRequestURI().contains("A"))))
                    .hasAnyRole("editor", "admin").and().authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(req -> (req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.toString())
                            && req.getRequestURI().equals("/A")))
                    .hasAnyRole("user", "editor", "admin")
                    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signin").permitAll().anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("admin").and()                
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthTokenFilter jwtRequestFilter() throws Exception
        {
            return new AuthTokenFilter();
        }
    
    }
```

Note that I did not fully explain the complexity of the situation but I wanted to paint a scenario, where I would need to do more than match Paths to determine the authorized roles.
The Example Above does not seem to function as aspected (For example i get 403 forbidden for every user on every endpoint but /signin works as aspected)  and I am at a loss as to what I need to do to ensure all endpoints are covered by the filterchain so that there is no unsecured endpoint and also that every user gets the correct access.

A decrypted JWT looks as follows:

```
  {
      "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyZWRha3RldXIiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJyZWRha3RldXIiXSwiZXhwIjoxNjQ3ODg4Njg4LCJpYXQiOjE2NDc4ODE0ODh9.8umzxQ_xqyca-wiMVGTiMLI9vhyQfJfTslNnRAAyn47hOJdN-231fFouAvKj71UUpfgpoa1tmLs9mH3Oy00poA",
      "userName": "admin",
      "roles": [
        "admin"
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So i managed to get it to work as required, but I am still not convinced this is best practice:

I switched the position of the permitAll(), clause and was missing the usage of one more authorizeRequests(). I will probably put the Boolean Expressions inside private Methods for readability next, though if there is an easier/ better solution i would apreciate any hints. Also I had to use hasAuthority instzead of hasRole due to Naming conventions.

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signin").permitAll().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(req -> (req.getRequestURI().contains("B") && !req.getRequestURI().contains("delete") && !req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.DELETE.toString())
                            || (req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.toString())
                                    && req.getRequestURI().contains("A"))))
                    .hasAnyAuthority("editor", "admin").and().authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(req -> (req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.toString())
                            && req.getRequestURI().equals("/A")))
                    .hasAnyAuthority("user", "editor", "admin")
                    .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                    .hasAuthority("admin").and()                
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthTokenFilter jwtRequestFilter() throws Exception
        {
            return new AuthTokenFilter();
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm sorry it was late and I wanted to add the answer before sleeping. I added a short explanation for my changes.